# Dynamically created checkbox input form elements are not posting to php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to add some dynamic checkboxes to the form based on the ajax post I receive from the server.  Each time the user changes some select fields I get a new set of checkboxes and refresh the Extras area.  I receive the postresult back ok and I can add them to the form. I can also do some calculations with them after I add them to the form.

But I can not post them to the server using forms submit button. Server receives all the fields from the form originally created.

HTML

```
<td><span id=ExtrasArea onchange=''></span></td>
```

Javascript - it runs when one of the select fields are changed

```
function onJoborItemChange() {  
    var job      = document.getElementById('Job').value; 
    var itemtype = document.getElementById('ItemType').value;

    $.post('xyz.php', { Job: job, ItemType: itemtype }, function(postresult) { 
        $('#ExtrasArea').html(postresult);
    });         
};
```

Comment: What does the html of the `form` look like? It appears you're using jQuery - is there some reason you also use `document.getElementById('Job')` rather than using jQuery's `$('#Job')`? And what is the value of `postresult` when it returns?

Comment: No Reason specifically to use document.getElementById('Job') instead of $('#Job'). My form tag was within a <div><table><tr><form ...

I also removed onchange='' from <span> tag.

I removed it from that location and I put it before the <div> and it is working now.  But I want to know why it did not work within <div> or <table> tags.  Now it is  <form><div><table><tr>...

Comment: postresult is an html table of preformatted checkboxes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure span's dont have an onchange event...

Comment: Thank you for responses.  
As I stated above I solved the problem by taking the form tag outside of the table and div tags.
But I still don't know why it is not working if the form tag is within div or table tags.  

Does anybody know the answer?